# How do provisioning profiles actually *work* in iOS and Xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to understand signing identities and provisioning profiles in iOS development. (Let us focus on development for now and not distribution via app-store. One issue at a time)

**Note:** I'm not looking for a how-to, but rather a general conceptual overview. In fact, Xcode seems to have taken care of all of it for me in some mysterious fashion, and things seem to work, but I want to understand what it actually did, and how it all fits together.

### Signing Identities

I think I understand signing identities. Here is how I think it works (let me know if I'm mistaken):

Apple has decided that users should not be able to run any random application on iOS and part of the technology it has used to implement this selectiveness is code signing.

Code signing is process of encrypting a hash of the binary with a private key and including the encrypted hash along with the binary. This is now a **signed** binary. Also included along with the binary is a certificate signed by Apple with includes the public key part of the key pair and effectively says that a binary signed with the private key that corresponds to the public key in the certificate is approved by Apple to run.

When iOS is asked to launch an app, it looks to see if the certificate is valid and that the app is indeed signed by the private key corresponding to the public key in the certificate. If everything is good, it launches the app.

### Provisioning Profiles

This is where my understanding of things start to break down. Here is what (I think) I know:

Code signing as described above can't be the whole story in the implementation of selectiveness. As a developer I can get a key pair and a certificate from Apple and I can sign my code with it. But that actually won't run as-is on an iOS device, as indeed it should not. If it did, then all one needs to build an app that runs on every iOS device is a developer account, and anyone can get that (well, anyone that can afford $100 a year).

What explains this is that the certificate I get from Apple is a **developer certificate** and that doesn't actually tell iOS that the app signed with the (private key corresponding to the) certificate is approved to run. It simply says that it is built by a valid developer. In order for iOS to decide that it is OK to run, it needs some additional information. I believe that information is what is stored in **development provisioning profile**.

The profile seems to associate developers, applications ids, and devices, saying in effect that applications with the id specified in the profile, built by the developers specified in the profile, are ok to run in the devices specified by the profile.

### The Actual Questions

What I don't understand is that the provisioning profile must:

1. Be available on the device. iOS on the device is the entity that is in the end making the decision whether to run the app or not, so it must look through the provisioning profiles to decide. **How do the profiles get to the device?**
2. Be certified by Apple. If the profile is not certified by Apple, then I can associate any app I want to my developer certificate and get it to run. **How does that certification happen? Or is there some other mechanism at work?**

Comment: Xcode connects to Apple and manages the profiles for you, but if you log in to your account at https://developer.apple.com you can see them and manage them yourself.  The provisioning profile is signed by Apple and installed to the device by Xcode when you deploy your app.  Because it is signed by Apple, iOS trusts it.  The provisioning profile authorises an app with a certain bundle id to run on the devices in the profile

Comment: Watch this: https://vimeo.com/235055677